# Why did i get an error(Expected declaration) when i add my database.reference?

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am new to swift and firebase. But i will try to make both and Google Login and an email/password Authentication with Firebase. And I getting the error: Expected declaration. Hope anyone can help me. it worked before I add the Google login code to Xcode.

```
var currenUser: User?

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var collectionTextField: [UITextField]!

    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Google login
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

    dbRef = Database.database().reference()

        for textField in self.collectionTextField {

            textField.delegate = self

    }

func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: {
            (user, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("Sign in error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            self.dbRef.child("usersID").child(user!.uid).child("info").setValue(["email": user!.email])

            print("user logged in: \(String(describing: user?.displayName))")

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignIn", sender: nil)
        })
    }
```

[image: Error shown here]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code is defining `dbRef` outside of any function. Perhaps you meant to put that code in `viewDidLoad()`?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Google login
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()


    dbRef = Database.database().reference()

        for textField in self.collectionTextField {
            textField.delegate = self
        }

}
```